# Too big of a sofa

Tags: prepositional-phrases, adjective-phrases

These kinds of expressions akin to measure quantifiers just blow my mind. For me it has to be "*too big gulp of whiskey*" and "*too big sofa*". Especially **c)**, it sounds like you placed *a part* of the sofa in your room, not the entire thing. Can you break down and explain this structure?

> a) "Could" is a little bit more difficult *of a modal verb* because it has many meanings.
>
> b) I took *too big of a gulp* of whiskey.
>
> c) I put *too big of a sofa* in my room, so there is no space.

Comment: I've corrected them. It is difficult to show to you what is wrong with them since you all are accustomed to them. But for my natural non-English logic this sentences look gross. Let me try: you can put in a room a small sofa, a big or a regular one, you cannot put big **of a sofa**, it sounds like you can choose what **amount** of the particulat sofa you can put in a room. "Oh my god, I put in a room too big of a sofa, let me bail out a little bit of it. OK, now it's just right."

Comment: You're right, you cannot put "big of a sofa". The 'too' part is not optional. The phrase is "too [adjective] of a [noun]". If I put too big of a sofa in a room, then cut part of it off so it wasn't too big anymore, then it would indeed become smaller. However, it probably wouldn't be a sofa anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the relevant "usage note" from [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/of?s=t), as cited in [an answer to a similar question on ELU.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/30012/2637)

> ***Of*** is sometimes added to phrases beginning with the adverb *how* or *too*  followed by a descriptive adjective: *How long of a drive will it be? It's too hot of a day for tennis.*
>
> This construction is probably modeled on that in which ***how*** or ***too*** is followed by ***much***,  an unquestionably standard use in all varieties of speech and writing:
> ***How much of a problem** will that cause the government?*

I'm not going to stick my neck out and say *too big **of** a* is "substandard", but it's definitely "nonstandard", and is normally only encountered in informal speech.

---

But note that whereas ***of*** is *optional, but nonstandard*, the word ***a*** is *absolutely essential* in this context.

Answer (score 7):

I think your confusion comes from the use of the word "of".

The word "of" in English can be used when speaking about a part of something. Like "the door OF my house", "the arm OF the chair". But it can also be used when speaking of a characteristic or attribute of something. "The height OF my brother", "the speed OF my car".

When we want to talk about the attribute of something rather than the thing itself, we sometimes use the adjective as a noun. But then we need to turn the noun -- the thing itself -- into a modifier, which we do by putting "of" in front of it. I'm not sure if this is strictly grammatically correct, but it's common in informal speech if not in more formal speech.

It would be perfectly good English to say "I took too big a drink". But if we want to emphasize that it was the size of the drink rather than the drink itself that was the issue, we say "I took too big of a drink."

Likewise, "I put a sofa in the room that was too big." Normal phrasing. "I put too big of a sofa in the room." Commonly said. Side note: I don't think a native speaker would say this without the "of", i.e. would NOT say "I put too big a sofa in the room". Maybe possibly "I put a too-big sofa in the room".

Comment: So, "_too big of a sofa_" is **semantically equall** to "_a too-big sofa_"?

Comment: I think that last paragraph is completely wrong. Per [this answer on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/30012/2637) covering the same usage, including **of** in such constructions is, if not exactly "non-standard", at least primarily restricted to informal spoken contexts. As dictionary.com says, things like *?how big **of** a problem* are probably modelled on the perfectly standard *how **much of** a problem*, where it would be very unusual (and probably unacceptable to most) to omit the **of**.

Comment: @Fumblefingers I'm not sure where you're disagreeing with me. I said using "of" in such phrases is "not ... strictly grammatically correct but it's common in informal speech". Or are you saying that "I put too big a sofa in the room" is correct and commonly used?

Comment: @ Jay: I'm disagreeing with your assertion in the final paragraph that native speakers would normally include ***of*** there. Google Books claims 4810 instances of [put too big a](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22put+too+big+a%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but there are only 16 for [put too big **of** a](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22put+too+big+of+a%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22put+too+big+of+a%22&tbm=bks&ei=RuXNUfvZEvL44QTYzIBo&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48572450,d.bGE&fp=340a5a63302ed31b&biw=1186&bih=930) - and some of those aren't our context.

Comment: I took Jay's last paragraph to mean that the first quoted item was "normal," and the "too big of a" usage was "common."

Comment: @horatio: Read it again. He says *"I put a sofa in the room that was too big"* is "normal phrasing". Next he says *"I put too big of a sofa in the room"* is "commonly said", which I maintain is completely untrue. Then he says a native speaker would NOT say *"I put too big a sofa in the room"*, but the corpus evidence in my above comment shows that to be untrue as well. And as for *"a too-big sofa"*, I think that's basically just baby-talk.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, I'll take your word for it that your research shows that to be the more common phrasing. I was going on my own anecdotal experience. (Frankly I think both phrasings are awkward.)

Comment: @ Jay: Well, it's not just my word. The dictionary.com link in my answer strongly implies **of** is a "non-standard" form erroneously modelled on *too/how **much** of a [whatever]*. And [this one](http://ezinearticles.com/?Ignorance-in-Marketing---Is-Poor-Grammar-Making-You-Look-Stupid?&id=6511973) comes right out and says *one of the most prevalent of these [grammatical] errors involves the addition of the preposition "of" where it does not belong, as in "not too big 'of' a deal,"*. It's not actually a grammar site as such, but it *is* advising copywriters on "correct" grammar.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I said "your word for it THAT YOUR RESEARCH SHOWS ...". I didn't mean that I thought you just made this up, but rather that I was accepting your statement that indeed this is what you found, i.e. I'm not going to double-check. I don't see any reason for you to lie about it, so I believe you! It's not like this is some controversial political issue. :-)

Comment: Sure, it's not *that* big **of** an issue :) But the fact is that as I write, your answer has 4 upvotes and mine has only one. OP asks if **of** is acceptable in these constructions, and I say it's "non-standard, informal speech" (but not "unacceptable"). Unless I've totally misunderstood your last paragraph, you're saying it's actually the *norm*, and that native speakers wouldn't come out with OP's example (c) without including **of**. I've produced what seems to me like supporting evidence for my position, but apparently voters here don't agree - which strikes me as odd, to say the least.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I feel like you're getting strangely adversarial. We're all friends here. Your research was on books. That last paragraph refers to what native speakers *say*. I'm a little surprised that the construction without 'of' is more common in print, but I'll believe it. I have a hard time believing that it is more common in conversation. The examples *without* 'of' look awkward and strange to *me*.

Comment: @Graduate Yes. That's what it means. In the local dialect I'm used to, saying "too big a sofa" would sound slightly odd. It sounds like an excessively formal phrasing, perhaps used for humorous effect.

Comment: @DCShannon: I think in the vast majority of cases, the ***for me*** part of [*too big a job for me*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22too+big+a+job+for+me%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) suggests at the very least an "informal" register, if not actual *conversation*. Google Books says it has 3140 hits, compared to just 10 for [*too big **of** a job for me*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22too+big+of+a+job+for+me%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). And I bet the preference would be even more marked for *too **small** a job for me* if it occurred often enough to check out.

Answer (score 1):

In British English one would say:

> "It's too hot a day for tennis"

but *never*:

> "It's too hot **of** a day for tennis."

One might say

> "He's too big a blighter to punch on the nose."

but *never*

> "He's too big **of** a blighter to punch on the nose."

You might protest,

> "Cecilia is too nice a girl to have said a thing like that."

but never

> "Cecilia is too nice **of** a girl to have said a thing like that."

I can finish by saying,

> "You're too intelligent a person to make this mistake."

but *not*

> "You're too intelligent **of** a person to make this mistake."

Comment: Yeah, *of*-insertion is characteristic of informal American English, not British English.  At least as far as I'm aware, anyway; I'm an American English speaker.

Comment: Welcome to ELL Stack Exchange! By "English English" you mean British English, right?

Comment: Greetings DCShannon, I did mean English English, but the same holds for all the varieties of British speech. 

Here's Shakespeare in _All's Well That Ends Well_ [1.1], "Virginity by being once lost may be ten times found; by being ever kept, it is ever lost: **'tis too cold a companion**; away with 't!" 

Wise words. "'Tis too cold **of** a companion" would simply sound ridiculous and, that I think, is the ultimate answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

As an English prof (now retired), I do not recall my students, from 1964 to 2013, creating grammatically correct phrases composed of words like "too," "so," etc., followed by an adjective, then by "a" or "an", then by a noun. The word "of" did not appear in such phrases (after the adjective) unless the phrase "how much" started the phrase, which permits the use of "of" in certain instances.  Lately, there has been a tendency to insert "of" after the adjective in such construction. It is a  question of usage, not grammar rules. Everything changes in languages over time.  Preventing such changes is virtually impossible. I don't like phrases such as  "how big of a" but my protests will not prevail. Changes come as they will, and there is nothing one can do to stop them. Might as well try to stop a  speeding locomotive by standing in front of it.   How dumb of an effort would that be!  --Old Prof.

Comment: Funny stuff. I don't think I'd use this construct in a sentence like, "I put too big of a sofa in my room, so there is no space." Instead, I probably just say, "That sofa is too big – there's no space now." However, I **can** see myself slipping into this informal construct if I was asking a question, like: "How big of a sofa do you want?" It's hard to figure out when these wordings sound acceptable in casual conversation, and when they don't – much less explain why. (P.S. Welcome aboard, Prof.)