# Construction of "it's too hard a task"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

Why do we say "it's too hard a task" and not "it's a too hard task"?
Is there a rule for that?

Comment: Related (but not a dup, I think) is this question about [too big (of) a sofa](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/too-big-of-a-sofa)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I wouldn't call it a dupe either, mainly because here we have the omission of "of", which makes this even more confusing, I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_articles:

> In most cases, the article is the first word of its noun phrase, preceding
>   all other adjectives and modifiers.
>
> The little old red bag held a very big surprise.
>
> There are a few exceptions, however:
>
> - Certain determiners, such as all, both, half, double, precede the
>     definite article when used in combination (all the team, both the
>     girls, half the time, double the amount).
> - The determiner such and
>     exclamative what precede the indefinite article (such an idiot, what
>     a day!).
> - **Adjectives qualified by too, so, as and how generally
>     precede the indefinite article: too great a loss, so hard a problem,
>     as delicious an apple as I have ever tasted, I know how pretty a girl
>     she is.**
> - When adjectives are qualified by quite (particularly when it
>     means "fairly"), the word quite (but not the adjective itself) often
>     precedes the indefinite article: quite a long letter.

Comment: *Quite* can also precede the ***definite*** article - he was [quite **the** big man](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22quite+the+big+man%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)