# What is the grammar used in this sentence

Tags: grammar

“Love is too weak a word for the way I feel.” Can anyone explain to me what the grammar behind “too weak a word” is? Specifically the usage of ‘a’

Comment: This should help you: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7759/construction-of-its-too-hard-a-task

Comment: And a post on ELL said something helpful - that you almost never see the word "a" before "too" (You might see it in titles of stories or something of that nature)

Answer (score 0):

@Harith
This is a common sentence structure, NP1+Vbe+NP1, where the noun phrase after the verb of being functions as subject complement.
In "Love is too weak a word for the way I feel," "too weak a word" is a noun phrase that functions as subject complement of "Love".
Thx @Davo for the link that gives this:
'Adjectives qualified by too, so, as and how generally precede the indefinite article.'