# not that good (of) a person

Tags: prepositions, usage

Example sentence:

> I'm not that good (of) a person. I just did it for the money.

Should that *of* be there?

Note: Google Ngrams [says](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that%20good%20a%20person%2C%20that%20good%20of%20a%20person&year_start=1600&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthat%20good%20a%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20good%20of%20a%20person%3B%2Cc0) that *that good a of person* is more common than *that good of a person.*

Comment: American non standard regional.

Comment: You have misquoted the Ngrams chart.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adj + (of) a + noun construction.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/36616/adj-of-a-noun-construction) Also [Too big of a sofa](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/too-big-of-a-sofa) and probably others.

Comment: ...9 years ago, I didn't want to stick my neck out and say *too big **of** a [whatever]* is "substandard", but today I'll happily upvote @MichaelHarvey's first comment here! :) But I should say I really don't like ***It's not much of a problem*** without ***of***.